# Parse_dates in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

The following code can't parse my date column into dates from csv file.

```
data=pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv',parse_dates=True,keep_date_col = True)
```

or

```
data=pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv',parse_dates=[0])
```

data is like following

```
date          value 
30MAR1990    140000 
30JUN1990    30000  
30SEP1990    120000  
30DEC1990    34555
```

What did I do wrong? Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Your data is not in csv format... dont use `pd.read_csv()`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is a non-standard format, so not caught by the default parser, you can pass your own:

```
In [11]: import datetime as dt

In [12]: dt.datetime.strptime('30MAR1990', '%d%b%Y')
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(1990, 3, 30, 0, 0)

In [13]: parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%d%b%Y')

In [14]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)
Out[14]:
        date  value
0 1990-03-30  140000
1 1990-06-30   30000
2 1990-09-30  120000
3 1990-12-30   34555
```

Another option is to use to_datetime *after* you've read in the strings:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just find out that parse_dates is really time consuming for a large file.

Comment: @user3576212 yes, you're moving from fast Cython reading of csv to python for the datetime. Much better to use to_datetime imo.

Comment: We'll, I tried "to date". But it's just as slow. I guess it's due to the date format.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, but writing True as [0] is terrible.

Comment: @Hakaishin that's not True, that's the columns indexes which are dates to be parsed

Comment: Dammit, you are so fast. just realized and wanted to delete my comment^^

Comment: @Hakaishin no worries

Comment: Where does pandas document what it considers the standard formats?

Comment: This answer provides a solution but it is as well incorrect. 
'30MAR1990'  is in standard format and it can be caught by a default parser if you tell it explicitly the name of the column.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `date_parser` argument to read_csv

```
In [62]: from pandas.compat import StringIO

In [63]: s = """date,value 
30MAR1990,140000 
30JUN1990,30000  
30SEP1990,120000  
30DEC1990,34555
"""

In [64]: from pandas.compat import StringIO

In [65]: import datetime
```

`date_parser` expects a function that will be called on an array of strings. `func` calls `datetime.datetime.strptime` on each string. Check out the `datetime` module in the python docs for more on the format codes.

```
In [66]: func = lambda dates: [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y') for x in dates]

In [67]: s = """date,value 
30MAR1990,140000 
30JUN1990,30000  
30SEP1990,120000  
30DEC1990,34555
"""

In [68]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=func)
Out[68]: 
        date  value 
0 1990-03-30  140000
1 1990-06-30   30000
2 1990-09-30  120000
3 1990-12-30   34555

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

`30MAR1990` ***is in standard format and it can be caught by a default parser*** if you tell it explicitly the name of the column:

Neither of these will work:

```
data=pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv',parse_dates=[0]) 
data=pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv',parse_dates=True,keep_date_col = True)
```

But if you parse `date` explicitly it will, as expected.

```
df = pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
```

Result:

```
date                value
1990-03-30 00:00:00 140000
1990-06-30 00:00:00 30000
1990-09-30 00:00:00 120000
1990-12-30 00:00:00 34555
```

There is no need for writing your own parser!
Simple & elegant!

Answer (score 0):

data=pd.read_csv('c:/data.csv',parse_dates=True,index_col='Date')

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SO.  Answers should include an explanation of your code.