# Pandas datetime: Year format issue while loading into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, reader

I have my dataset as below:

```
Sl.No   Date1
1   08-09-1990
2   01-06-1988
3   04-10-1989
4   15-11-1991
5   01-06-1968
```

When I tried  to load the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file",parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
```

I am getting the output as:

```
0   08-09-90
1   01-06-88
2   04-10-89
3   15-11-91
4   01-06-68
```

Problem is:

1. The date format is *dd-mm-YY* instead of *dd-mm-YYYY*
2. As a result when I try to convert datetime format the year 1968 is taken as 2068 (eg. Index 4 in output/sl.no 5 in input)

also as per suggested link [[how to specify the datetime format in read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862956/how-to-specify-the-datetime-format-in-read-csv])

i tried it was the same issue as before

and i also tried with [[time data does not match format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015711/time-data-does-not-match-format])

df=pd.read_csv("file",infer_datetime_format=True)
df[Date1]=pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

am facing ValueError '08-09-90' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to specify the datetime format in read\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862956/how-to-specify-the-datetime-format-in-read-csv)

Comment: I think this thread already has the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797491/parse-dates-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried the suggested answer even then the problem is same, The format of the year after loaded is in dd-mm-YY only.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try - It seems to work for me

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = '' # insert your files path here (I created a csv with columns 'SI_No' and 'Date' to test this and then copied your data)

df = pd.read_csv(filepath, parse_dates=['Date'])

df = df.set_index('SI_No')

df

                Date
SI_No
1     1990-08-09
2     1988-01-06
3     1989-04-10
4     1991-11-15
5     1968-01-06
```