# pandas dataframe index remove date from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

File dataexample_df.txt:

```
2020-12-04_163024 26.15 26.37 19.40 24.57
2020-12-04_163026 26.15 26.37 19.20 24.57
2020-12-04_163028 26.05 26.37 18.78 24.57
```

I want to read it in as pandas dataframe where the index column has only the time part in format `'%H:%M:%S'`, without the date.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dataexample_df.txt", sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                       1      2      3      4
0
2020-12-04_163024  26.15  26.37  19.40  24.57
2020-12-04_163026  26.15  26.37  19.20  24.57
2020-12-04_163028  26.05  26.37  18.78  24.57
```

However, wanted output:

```
              1      2      3      4
0
16:30:24  26.15  26.37  19.40  24.57
16:30:26  26.15  26.37  19.20  24.57
16:30:28  26.05  26.37  18.78  24.57
```

I have tried different `date_parser=` -functions (cf. Answers in [Parse_dates in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797491/parse-dates-in-pandas))
but get only error messages. Also, somewhat relevant is [Python/Pandas convert string to time only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801321/11199684) but no luck, I'm stuck. I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your `df` to be this:

```
In [121]: df
Out[121]: 
                       1      2      3      4
0                                            
2020-12-04_163024  26.15  26.37  19.40  24.57
2020-12-04_163026  26.15  26.37  19.20  24.57
2020-12-04_163028  26.05  26.37  18.78  24.57
```

You can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with [`Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
In [122]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)
In [127]: df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0].str.replace('_', ' ')).dt.time

In [130]: df.set_index(0, inplace=True)

In [131]: df
Out[131]: 
              1      2      3      4
0                                   
16:30:24  26.15  26.37  19.40  24.57
16:30:26  26.15  26.37  19.20  24.57
16:30:28  26.05  26.37  18.78  24.57
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get error message from `df['0']`. It does work if I use `df[0]`and `df.set_index(0, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Here, I created a simple function to formate your datetime column, Please try this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=" ", header=None)

def format_time(date_str):
    # split date and time
    time =  iter(date_str.split('_')[1])
    # retun the time value adding
    return ':'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(time, time))

df[0] = df[0].apply(format_time)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great example how to use `apply` method, I never knew much about that. But this still requires one more operation at the end: `df.set_index(0, inplace=True)` like in @Mayank answer above.

Comment: @user9393931 Also to add, `apply` is basically loops under the hood. So it is a bit slower when compared to the functions I used in my answer.

Comment: @user9393931 agreed with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it what the format of your date is using the `format` argument (otherwise you'll get an error):

```
# gives an error:
pd.to_datetime('2020-12-04_163024')

# works:
pd.to_datetime('2020-12-04_163024', format=r'%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
```

So you can apply this to your dataframe and then access the time by using `dt.time`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format=r'%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S').dt.time
```

That will give you the time as an object, but if you want to format it, just use something like this:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'` from the line `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format=r'%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S').dt.time` ?